# WatchKit app is missing its app extension

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I have added Watch Extenwion into my old app, but when I'm trying to launch it on simulator I'm getting this error:

[image]

I found, that it is tipical issue ip you are working with iPad, but I've turned off ipad compatibility.

Do somebody know how to fix it?

Comment: Did you solve this?  I am seeing the same issue.. after trying to add a watch extension to my iPhone App.